# Jmeter HttpRequest shows "browser is currently set to block cookies"

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I am new to Jmeter. I tried to send an HTTP request but the HTTP response showed "cookie is blocked"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipsbr.png)

I tried to create the HTTP Cookie Manager and set the cookie policy as Compatibility but doesn't work.
and also tried to set CookieManager.save.cookies=true in JMeter.properties file, but both don't work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a very first request - no cookies are involved, most probably the application you're testing tries to set a cookie via JavaScript and not using [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header

As per [Apache JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So you need to inspect the page, you're opening using [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and if the cookies are being created/set by JavaScript - you will need to replicate the same logic using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://groovy-lang.org/), check out [Modifying Cookies in JMeter with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/modifying-cookies-in-jmeter-with-groovy/) article for more details.